# CodeIgniter 3 removing index.php from url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I do everything is done but still not working. i don't know what wrong with me. 
I have do that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on my apache2 server. In config, `$config['index_page'] = ''`;
and `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';`
it is my base url `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/RB';`
My codeignitor root .htaccess file contains,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

this is the code given on their official [website](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i have tried this but not working.. please tell me other thing.

Comment: Hey, try changing base_url to this → `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/rb/';` <br> notice the trailing slash(/) and lowercase letters and change your folder name to lowercase. (URL should always be lowercase)

Comment: I did it but still not working.